How to define styles for a mesh based on a function of element index
My main objective is to have control over style of each element in a mesh. I don't quite understand how ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex works. It looks very cool and versatile but I need some easier examples to understand. I have looked at for example link1,
linked2. One reason it is confusing for me is that these examples assigns VertexColors->, but the elements are colored?
And I used help to see it has the following options:
ContinuousElementID->Automatic
CoordinateConversion->Identity
MeshElement->Automatic
MeshElementIDStyle->None
MeshElementMarkerStyle->None
MeshElementStyle->None
MessageHead->Automatic
ContentSelectable->Automatic
TextureMapping->Automatic
VertexColors->Automatic
VertexNormals->Automatic
VertexTextureCoordinates->None

but it would be helpful if someone can explain with simpler examples. For example if we have a field value for each element (say mesh["quality"] as an example), or even simpler, if we want each row or column have a different color in:
<< NDSolve`FEM`
nx = ny = 10;
coordinates = 
  Flatten[Table[{r  Cos[\[Theta]], r  Sin[\[Theta]]}, {r, 1., 2., 
     1/(ny - 1)}, {\[Theta], 0., 2  Pi/3., (2  Pi/3.)/(nx - 1)}], 1];
incidents = 
  Flatten[Table[{j*nx + i, 
     j*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i}, {i, 1, 
     nx - 1}, {j, 1, ny - 1}], 1];
ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
  "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents]}];
ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
  "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents]}];
%["Wireframe"]

how is it done?
Update: Some progress I made based on Michael E2's comment that these are just graphics polygons, was the following:
polygons = Polygon[coordinates[[#]]] & /@ incidents;
rowColors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[0, 1, ny - 1];
coloredPolygons = 
  Table[{rowColors[[Mod[j - 1, ny - 1, 1] + 1]], 
    Polygon[coordinates[[incidents[[j]]]]]}, {j, Length[incidents]}];
Graphics[coloredPolygons]


But if anyone can think of a more streamlined solutions, I'd like to learn about it.

ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[] creates a GraphicsComplex[] of polygons (Polygon[]), in effect a linear representation of the mesh no matter what the mesh order is. I doubt one can get a quadratic representation. Options include the options of GraphicsComplex[] (like VertexColors) and options explained in this tech note. I don't have all this stuff memorized, so to use it, I go look this stuff up. Some I can guess/test, like "CoordinateConversion" -> f replaces coordinates p by f[p].

Thanks, I looked into that link but I guess based on your comments there is no way to natively have control over elements of the mesh? I see some options maybe by creating regions and then combining RegionMarker and MeshElementStyle etc. similar to https://wolfram.com/xid/0pect4bpmx8qfv136bx93o9az2-s7h02q but that looks way too complicated in my opinion for something that could be as simple as giving a certain style for each element number.

Also, if I understand your comment correctly, you mean there is only a linear interpolation of node values that is happening under the hood and that is only a function of node coordinates? I changed the title. Based on your comment, I feel like this is a more accurate way to ask the question.

Re "to natively have control over elements of the mesh": See this other tech note. Applying MeshRegion to the element mesh may give you the control you want. Re "linear": The graphics have nothing to do with interpolation or differential equations. By linear, I meant the polygons are straight-lined (usually triangles) and the second-order points (aka "incidents") are ignored (in the graphics). I believe that in boundary elements, these points may be moved off the straight line connecting the vertices.

You may be interested in this question, which points out that the strange behavior of the edges may be due to a bug.

@MichaelE2 thanks for letting me know. I think I used your solution and worked some more on it but still haven't found a general way to plot nice contours like the FEM tech doc example.  I will keep an eye on the related question you linked.

I rather like the OP's straight-up graphics-geometry way. I don't think the FEM functionality can add much to it. But here's a way, in which we use the "Wireframe" method of ElementMesh[] to call ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[] (probably there is no need to call ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[] directly):
Block[{nx, ny, incidents, coordinates, rowColors},
 nx = ny = 10;
 coordinates = 
  Flatten[Table[{r   Cos[\[Theta]], r   Sin[\[Theta]]}, {r, 1., 2., 
     1/(ny - 1)}, {\[Theta], 0., 2   Pi/3., (2   Pi/3.)/(nx - 1)}], 1];
 incidents = 
  Flatten[Table[{j*nx + i, 
     j*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i}, {i, 1, 
     nx - 1}, {j, 1, ny - 1}], 1];
 mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents, Range@Length@incidents]}];
 rowColors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[0, 1, ny - 1];
 
 mesh["Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> 
    Table[Directive[EdgeForm[], 
      FaceForm@rowColors[[Mod[j - 1, ny - 1, 1] + 1]]], {j, 
      Length[incidents]}]]]
 ]


A slight refactoring of the OP's code to use GraphicsComplex[]:
Block[{nx, ny, incidents, coordinates, rowColors},
 nx = ny = 10;
 coordinates = 
  Flatten[Table[{r   Cos[\[Theta]], r   Sin[\[Theta]]}, {r, 1., 2., 
     1/(ny - 1)}, {\[Theta], 0., 2   Pi/3., (2   Pi/3.)/(nx - 1)}], 1];
 incidents = 
  Table[{j*nx + i, 
    j*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i}, {j, 1, 
    ny - 1}, {i, 1, nx - 1}];
 rowColors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[0, 1, ny - 1];
 
 Graphics[{
   GraphicsComplex[
    coordinates,
    Riffle[RotateRight@Rest@rowColors, Polygon /@ incidents]
    ]
   }]
 ]
(* image as above *)


No actually your solution works! My solution still showed the edges and I couldn't get rid of it with even nx=ny=100 and playing with EdgeForm  thikness and opacity. It wasn't showing a continuous nice looking transition. But your GraphicsComplex works and looks great. Thank you.

@MathX I'm not sure why there's a difference with the edges, but adding the color to EdgeForm[] fixes your code: coloredPolygons =    Table[{Directive[EdgeForm@rowColors[[Mod[j - 1, ny - 1, 1] + 1]],       FaceForm@rowColors[[Mod[j - 1, ny - 1, 1] + 1]]],      Polygon[coordinates[[incidents[[j]]]]]}, {j, Length[incidents]}];

I am still seeing the edges, no matter what I do including using the code you commented above. Unless I use GraphicsComplex it doesn't become seamless.

@MathX I'm on a Mac (ARM). Maybe it's a system thing. I don't get edge lines; moreover, I don't think one should get them with solid-color edges matching the face color.
